# Aligning coordinate systems

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, transformation

Let's say I have 2 coordinate systems as it is shown in image attached  [image]

How can I align this coordinate systems? I know that I need to translate second coordinate system around X with 180 grads, and then translate it to (0, 0) of the first coordinate system, but I have some troubles with doing it getting wrong results. Will really appreciate any detailed answer.

EDIT: Actually (0, 0) of second coordinate system is in the same point like Y of the first coordinate system.

Comment: Are you really just moving Y's origin and flipping the Y coordinate in this scenario? You should be able to multiply by an appropriate translation matrix and a scale matrix with -1 for Y. Rotating by 180 degrees is going to invert your X coordinate too, and judging by the diagram you only want Y inverted. Alternatively, you could rotate and then flip X back; there's no point of reference to show how your origins in both diagrams are truly related.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman I need to "put" (0,0) of second coordinate system, to (0,0) of first coordinate system, and to rotate Y around X, so in result to have only first coordinate system(so that any point in second coordinate system will be identical to the one in first).

Comment: Be aware, there is no way rotating is going to solve this problem. You have two problems here, actually. Your Y coordinate system is changing directions but X is (supposed to be) staying the same. If you rotate 180 degrees, then a point at (-Y,X) is going to be off-screen. You'd need to use (-Y,-X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important piece of information is where is the second coordinate system's origin - namely `(a,b)`.

Once you know that,  all you need is:

```
QPointF pos1; // original position
QTransform t;
t.scale(1, -1);
t.translate(a, -b+1);
QPointF pos2 = pos1 * t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find correct values of a,b,c,d,Ox,Oy in:

> X = a * x + b * y + Ox
>
> Y = c * x + d * y + Oy

where x,y are the coordinates on the point in one system and X,Y in the other one.

In your case, a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = -1.
Ox,Oy is the offset between the Origins.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i am not sure if it will fit me. The equations that you wrote if I understand clearly are actually rotation matrix and translation matrix (in this case vector). Where a=cos(180), b=-sin(180), c=sin(180), d=Cos(180). But the issue is for example when applying this to glwidget anything drawn in widget is given as in first coordinate system (though mouse coordinates are got as in second coordinate system), if i would track the mouse position, and click on (1,1) of first coordinate system, the output will be not (1,1).

Comment: You miss the homothety part (possible for each axis). Your values are a=d=-1 which is a rotation. In my case, The y axis is mirrored (without rotation).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem with rotating 180 degrees, it not only affects the direction of your Y coordinate but also X.

```
Y             X <--+
^        =>        |
|                  v
+--> X             Y
```

What you probably meant to do was translate the point at Y and then invert your Y-coordinate. You can do this like so:

1. Translate Y to new origin
2. Scale (1, -1)

```
Y             +--> X
^        =>   |
|             v
+--> X        Y
```

After more thought, I have to wonder, why are you doing this transformation in the first place? Is it because of differences in OpenGL coordinates and the coordinates Qt uses for its window?

If this is the case, you can actually alter your projection matrix... If you're using an orthographic matrix, for instance:

Try `glOrtho (0, X, 0, Y, -1, 1);` instead of the traditional `glOrtho (0, X, Y, 0, -1, 1);`

If you opt to do this, you will probably need to change the winding direction of your polygon "front faces". OpenGL defaults to CCW, change it to `glFrontFace (GL_CW)` and this should prevent weird lighting / culling behavior.