# Mouse events in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, mousemove, mouseclick-event

I have 3 events defined as follows:

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *eventMove);
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *eventPress);
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *releaseEvent);
```

Now, let's say I want to do something when the mouse is clicked and moved until the mouse is released. 
e.g. Give an output `!` until the conditions described upper are true.

EDIT: I have tried to set a global variable let's say `bool a` and make it `true` in `mousePressEvent(...)`, `false` in `mouseReleaseEvent(...)`, but when in `mouseMoveEvent(...)` the `a` is always `true`, even when button is released.

Comment: I don't understand your goals completely, but wouldn't `QMouseEvent::buttons` in `mouseMoveEvent` is enough?

Comment: I have ...::buttons in QMouseEvent::buttons, and ...::button in others, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the same code as in:

[Tracking mouse coordinates in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551387/tracking-mouse-coordinates-in-qt/18552004#18552004)

But without the `setMouseTracking(true)`. With `setMouseTracking(false)` (the default) the `void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` method is only called, when a mousebutton is pressed.

No `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *eventPress)` or `mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *releaseEvent)` needed for your requirements.