# How can I detect mouse motion in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing something using Qt Widgets (C++). I need to detect when mouse is moved (either outside or inside the application window) and update cursor coordinates on my app window.
I can't find any way to do it. I wonder if it's possible to use connect( ... ) statement.

Target is Win10.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559791/mouse-events-in-qt

Comment: And [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551387/tracking-mouse-coordinates-in-qt/18552004#18552004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551387/tracking-mouse-coordinates-in-qt/18552004#18552004)

Comment: [Getting MouseMoveEvents in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935021/getting-mousemoveevents-in-qt)

Comment: No dupe. That only considers mouse interaction in the app itself, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the best way to do it is using WinAPI through the WH_MOUSE_LL
hook, as it seems Qt can only manage mouse events related to its own app.

I did it this way:

```
SetWindowsHookEx( WH_MOUSE_LL, doSomethingWhenMouseMoves, NULL, 0 );
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)