# Distinguish mouse click between touchpad and mouse button

Tags: c++, qt, click

I am doing an experiment with a Qt app and it would be extremely helpful to be able to differentiate clicks from the mouse left button vs the ones coming from the touchpad. For what I have read, there is no documentation about it.

On the other hand, I have read this SO question [Tracking mouse coordinates in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551387/tracking-mouse-coordinates-in-qt)

and I know that it's also possible to track mouse coords, in other elements but haven't found a way to do it on a qpushbutton.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to differentiate them? A mouse click is a mouse click, regardless of where it came from

Comment: Not really answering your question but related: you can [track special touchpad events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnativegestureevent.html#details). I don't know if it's possible to differentiate touchbad simple click from mouse click.

Comment: I haven't tested it personnaly, but maybe you could have a look at [QTouchEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#details).